# jQuery 1.4.2 - Ajax & increasing IE 8 Process Handles

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm requesting every second some data over $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ServiceEndpointUrl",
   data: "",
   success: function(result) {
      ... Do Work ...
} } } } });
```

This code leads into an continuous growing number of handles in IE 8 (Windows 7 / verified with Task Manager & Process Explorer).
Firefox & Chrome does not have this problem.

This page is displayed all day long - this leads into thousands of handles & will sometimes crash the complete browser.

My workaround is to reload the complete page every hour - but this can't be the solution ;-)

Any suggestions how to "close" these Ajax-Handles?

thx

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. But maybe using COMET instead of AJAX could have avoid this problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: @Claudio: Sounds reasonable, but comet along with xhr readystate3 will not work in IE